# MSSQL Speed Up Query 365 Millon Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have roughly 365 Million Rows inside my tables and each day we add an additional Million rows after the data is a year old it gets moved to a different table that archives our data.

I have a PK Clustered index on DataCollectionID.

I have one other index: a Unique Nonclusted index on AssetID, DataPointID, and DatapointDate

I need to run multiple select queries against the table pretty quickly... here is my select Query:

```
SELECT [DataPointID]
  ,[SourceTag]
  ,[DatapointDate]
  ,[DataPointValue]
FROM DataCollection
Where 
  DatapointDate >= '2012-09-07' AND 
  DatapointDate < '2012-09-08' AND
  DataPointID = 1100
ORDER BY DatapointDate
```

This query should return 8,640 rows which it does but it takes 00:00:08 (8 seconds) to execute. Even if I said give me top 10 it still takes 8 seconds. Can someone please help me speed up this process?

Comment: Is it just this table that gives slow performance?

Comment: I've voted to close this question to get it migrated to dba.stackexchange.com, I believe that this is a better fit over there

Comment: It should be moved once we've determined it's a configuration issue. If he hasn't put this into a stored proc, it's still a coding/design issue.

Comment: What about a clustered index on DatapointDate? It means you'll have to remove it from where it was, but if dates are heavily used overall in your queries, it seems an option to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a more effective index to help this query would be on DataPointID, DataPointDate, in that order.  This will allow the optimizer to quickly narrow down the field with an equality operator on the first index column, then find the date range within that set.

There are some good examples of indexes and similar queries here:

http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Index_Selectivity_and_Column_Order

Answer (score 0):

If this is dynamic SQL, you should put it into a stored procedure, and remember to use `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Otherwise it sounds like a hardware problem: in which case more memory might help.

Comment: Ok let me try to put it into a SP

Comment: I created a Stored Procedure and it still takes 8 seconds to execute

Answer (score 0):

You need a better covering index, something like:

```
create index _idx ON DataCollection ( DataPointDate, DataPointId )
include ( SourceTag, DataPointValue )
```

You generally want the most selective ( ie most unique ) column at the front of the index, so this may be dataPointDate or dataPointId depending on your data.